# erro sqlite3.OperationalError

Tags: python, sqlite3

Estou tendo um problema com sqlite3 em python, alguém pode me ajudar?

o erro é esse:

```
:~$ python3 05_create_data_param.py
Nome: Henry Elias Carlos Eduardo dos Santos
Usuário: Henry94
Senha: mGq0HJAM2C
Data de nascimento: 08/01/1994
CPF: 772.041.070-04
Email: henry_elias@chiba.net.br
Fone: (85) 3808-2828
Cidade: Fortaleza
UF: CE
Criado em (yyyy-mm-dd): 10/06/2016
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "05_create_data_param.py", line 24, in <module>
""", (p_nome, p_usuario, p_senha, p_nascimento, p_cpf, p_email, p_fone,p_cidade, p_uf, p_criado_em))
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "de": syntax error
```

os códigos são esses:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sqlite3


conn = sqlite3.connect('clientes.db')

cursor = conn.cursor()


cursor.execute("""
CREATE TABLE clientes (
        id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
        nome TEXT NOT NULL,
        usuário TEXT NOT NULL,
        senha TEXT NOT NULL,
        data de nascimento DATE NOT NULL,
        cpf     VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL,        
        fone TEXT,
        cidade TEXT,
        uf VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
        criado_em DATE NOT NULL
);
""")

print('Tabela criada com sucesso.')

conn.close()
```

e

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('clientes.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()

p_nome = input('Nome: ')
p_usuario = input('Usuário: ')
p_senha = input('Senha: ')
p_nascimento = input('Data de nascimento: ')
p_cpf = input('CPF: ')
p_email = input('Email: ')
p_fone = input('Fone: ')
p_cidade = input('Cidade: ')
p_uf = input('UF: ')
p_criado_em = input('Criado em (yyyy-mm-dd): ')

cursor.execute("""
INSERT INTO clientes (nome, usuario, senha, data de nascimento, cpf, email, fone, cidade, uf, criado_em)
VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
""", (p_nome, p_usuario, p_senha, p_nascimento, p_cpf, p_email, p_fone, p_cidade, p_uf, p_criado_em))

conn.commit()

print('Dados inseridos com sucesso.')

conn.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro é simples, quando você cria uma coluna de uma tabela, ela não pode ter espaços. Quando se cria a tabela Clientes, mude a linha:

```
data de nascimento DATE NOT NULL,
```

para:

```
data_de_nascimento DATE NOT NULL,
```

Outra observação: é recomendado que não se use caracteres não ASCII (como acento, cedilha etc). Mude a linha:

```
usuário TEXT NOT NULL,
```

para

```
usuario TEXT NOT NULL,
```

Comment: nossa, que falta de atenção a minha... muito obrigado mesmo